# Product Attribute always returns null

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

my products have a custom attribute named producing_days

[image]

and im pretty sure that it has a value in catalog_product_entity_varchar
[image]

now I'm trying to access producing_days from quote item

```
/* $item is a quote item*/
$product = $item->getProduct();

$id = $product->getId(); //this works and return 3272
$producing_days = $product->getProducingDays(); //this returns null
```

I tried accessing it on stores 4, 14, and 19, and it's all null in there. and it shouldn't be an issue because the "All Stores" has value. any idea why I can't access the producing_days?

Comment: did you try `$product->getAttributeText('producing_days');` ?

Comment: Or make sure you are getting custom attribute while var_dump i.e `var_dump($product->getData());`

Comment: i already tried getAttributeText('producing_days'). and checking $product->getData() producing_days is not in there. do you an idea why its not being retrieved? it has an entry in the DB and also visible in the admin

Comment: @Pawan found the solution. i needed to retrieve the product from Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface. and there i have all my attributes. which is weird because i already have the product instance from the quote item. but im already stock here for so long, so i guess this will do

Comment: correct you need to load product by repo Or by factory!

Comment: Thanks @Pawan. i just find it weird because the quote item getProduct() already returns \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product. but for some reasons it doesnt have all the attributes i need and i need to load a new instance of the product. just thinking it might not be the best approach. but as long as it works haha.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this way, creates /etc/catalog_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="producing_days"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

it's a the fastest way to add a custom product attribute in the Quote item

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your product attribute available for your quote item by adding `catalog_attributes.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="producing_days"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that even if you can receive an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` as a return from calling other object's methods, only the repository model triggers all data loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $productId = $item->getProductId();
 $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
 $value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```